# Plotting flaws in Matplotlib

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, plot

Scatter plot using x,y coordinates proposes plots in Matplotlib that differ from those obtained using other programs. For example, here are the results of some PCA on the two fit score. The same graph using R and the same data provides different display…I also checked with Excell and Libreoffice : they provided the same display as R. 
Before Roaring against Matplotlib or report a bug, I would like to get other opinions and to check if I did things well. What are my flaws?

I checked that floats were not the problem, checked that coordinates order similarly,…
So plot with R:

```
mydata = read.csv("C:/Users/Anon/Desktop/data.txt")  # read csv file
summary(mydata)
attach(mydata) 
plot(mydata)
```

scatter plot made by R
[image]

Same data plotted with Matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import numpy as np
import os
# open the file with PCA results and convert it into float
file_data = os.getcwd() + "\\data.txt"
F = open(file_data, 'r')
DATA=F.readlines()
F.close()
for x in range(len(DATA)) :
    a = DATA[x]
    b = a.split(',')
    DATA[x] = b
for i in xrange(len(DATA)):
    for j in xrange(len(DATA[i])):
        DATA[i][j] = float(DATA[i][j])
print DATA[0]
X_train = np.mat(DATA)
print "X_train\n",X_train

mpl.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c='white')
mpl.show()
```

[image: scatter plot made by Matplotlib]
and results of printing X_train (so you can verify that data are the same)
[image]
With Excell:
[image]

data: (I cannot put all the data, please tell me how to join the *.txt file ~40.5 Ko)

```
0.02753547770433    -0.037999362802379
0.05179194064903    0.0257492713593311
-0.0272928319004863 0.0065143681863637
0.0891355504379135  -0.00801696955147688
0.0946809371499167  -0.00502202338807476
-0.0445799941736001 -0.0435759273767196
-0.333617999778119  -0.204222004815357
-0.127212025425053  -0.110264460064754
-0.0243459270896855 -0.0622273166478512
0.0497080821876597  0.0272080474151131
-0.181221703468915  -0.134945934382777
-0.0699503258694739 -0.0835239795690277
```

edit: So I yet exported PCA data (from scipy) into a text file and opened this common text file with python/matplotlib and R to avoid some prblms related to PCA. Plots were made after that handling (and the graph before PCA looks like a dome)

edit2: using numpy.loadtxt(), it displays as R but my custom method and numpy.loadtxt() provided the same data shape, size, type and values, so what's the mechanism involved?

```
X_train numpy.loadtxt()
[[ 0.02753548 -0.03799936]
 [ 0.05179194  0.02574927]
 [-0.02729283  0.00651437]
 ..., 
 [ 0.02670961 -0.00696177]
 [ 0.09011859 -0.00661216]
 [-0.04406559  0.09285291]] 
shape and size
(1039L, 2L) 2078

X_train custom-method
[[ 0.02753548 -0.03799936]
 [ 0.05179194  0.02574927]
 [-0.02729283  0.00651437]
 ..., 
 [ 0.02670961 -0.00696177]
 [ 0.09011859 -0.00661216]
 [-0.04406559  0.09285291]] 
shape and size
(1039L, 2L) 2078
```

Comment: What function did you use in R?

Comment: `here are the results of some PCA on the two fit score` I'm sure the problem is in the PCA (or in your input) rather than the plotting. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Can you post the data?

Comment: you are getting negative votes because you have not shown us a) data b) the code you used to generate the figures, which makes this question impossible to answer, and thus a bad question.

Comment: @sol: Could you post the Python code you used (and preferably the R code as well), even if you don't post the data?

Comment: un(-1) because you fixed the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are representing `X_train` as a matrix rather than a 2-dimensional array. That means that when you subset it with `X_train[:, 0]`, you aren't getting a 1-dimensional array- you are getting a matrix with one column (which matplotlib then tries to scatter). You can see for yourself by printing `X_train[:, 0]`.*

You can fix the problem simply by changing the line:

```
X_train = np.mat(DATA)
```

to

```
X_train = np.array(DATA)
```

---

*For example, on the data you posted, `X_train[:, 0]` is:

```
[[ 0.02753548]
 [ 0.05179194]
 [-0.02729283]
 [ 0.08913555]
 [ 0.09468094]
 [-0.04457999]
 [-0.333618  ]
 [-0.12721203]
 [-0.02434593]
 [ 0.04970808]
 [-0.1812217 ]
 [-0.06995033]]
```

Comment: thanks for clear explanations! I will have a look on difference between matrices and 2d-arrays Best, Sol ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the problem is im the code that reads in the array. You get the wrong dimension. Try using numpy.loadtxt instead. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: nice it works! But what can be the mechanism as when I print the data table, they have the same shape, type and values? Is it during the conversion into numpy matrix? X_train numpy.loadtxt()
[[ 0.02753548 -0.03799936]
 [ 0.05179194  0.02574927]
 [-0.02729283  0.00651437]
 ..., 
 [ 0.02670961 -0.00696177]
 [ 0.09011859 -0.00661216]
 [-0.04406559  0.09285291]] (1039L, 2L) 2078
X_train custom-method
[[ 0.02753548 -0.03799936]
 [ 0.05179194  0.02574927]
 [-0.02729283  0.00651437]
 ..., 
 [ 0.02670961 -0.00696177]
 [ 0.09011859 -0.00661216]
 [-0.04406559  0.09285291]] (1039L, 2L) 2078

Comment: @sol: See my answer for an explanation as to why- it's because it's a matrix, not a 2d array, and subsetting a matrix gets you another matrix, not a 1d array.